# How to traverse a list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation

It is known that $ g=A_{0} f\left(x_{0}\right)+A_{1} f\left(x_{1}\right)$.

When the function `f` can be selected from the list $\{x,x^2,x^3,x^4,\sin(x)\}$, what can I do to traverse `f` to get the following result:

```
A0*x0 + A1*x1
A0*x0^2 + A1*x1^2
A0*x0^3 + A1*x1^3
A0*x0^4 + A1*x1^4
A0*Sin[x0] + A1*Sin[x1]
```

**The source of the problem:**

We need to determine the nodes `x0`,`x1` and coefficients `A0`,`A1` of the integral formula $\int_{-1}^{1}  f(x) \mathrm{d} x \approx A_{0} f\left(x_{0}\right)+A_{1} f\left(x_{1}\right)$ so that this integral formula has the highest algebraic accuracy.

Comment: `Dot[{a0, a1}, #] &  /@  Function[x, {x, x^2, x^3, x^4, Sin[x]}][{x0, x1}]`

Comment: @LouisB Thank you for your method.

Comment: (-1) You should not change the question to a completely different question in the edit.

Comment: @xzczd 你要严于律己宽以待人，不要总盯着他人的缺点，这样不利于团结同志一起打鬼子。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Outer` with `Construct`

```
Outer[Construct, {# &, #^2 &, #^3 &, #^4 &, Sin}, {x0, x1}].{A0, A1}
```

Answer (score -1):

$\color{Gray}  {\text{(2001 武汉 岩石 数值分析 6)}} $

```
Solve[Outer[
    Construct, {1 & , #1 & , #1^2 & , #1^3 & }, {x0, x1}] . {A0, A1} == 
     Integrate[{1, x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -1, 1}], {x0, x1, A0, A1}]
```

Using the above code, we can get the answer of this question: `{{x0->1/Sqrt[3],x1->-(1/Sqrt[3]),A0->1,A1->1},{x0->-(1/Sqrt[3]),x1->1/Sqrt[3],A0->1,A1->1}}`.